# connect ssh key on server windows fail

Tags: ssh, openssh, public-key, windows-server-2019

I want to connect to a Windows server with an SSH key and if I connect via an SSH password, it's works, but if I via my SSH key, it fails

- I'm user on this server and my public key is `%UserProfile%/.ssh/authorized_keys`
- `sshd_config`:

  ```
  # Logging
  LogLevel DEBUG3

  # Authentication:
  PubkeyAuthentication yes
  AuthorizedKeysFile  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

  # override default of no subsystems
  Subsystem   sftp    sftp-server.exe
  ```

In the server log, I have:

```
Failed publickey for myuser from myLocalIP port 51845 ssh2: ED25519 SHA256:<mypubssh>
```

In the client log, I have:

```
$ ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 -l myUser -p 222 hostserver -vvv

  myuser@hostserver: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
```

Comment: Are you an Administrator? If so, does the same error occur if you add your SSH key to `%ProgramData%\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys`?

Comment: I'm not an Administrator, but i add my ssh key in %ProgramData%\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys

Answer (score 0):

Quick workaround, one can overwrite the existing key file with 521 key as below:

C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh-keygen.exe -b 521 -o -t ecdsa -f C:\ProgramData\ssh\ssh_host_ecdsa_key

then do Restart-Service sshd from the power shell